# How can i sort a map by its .second parameter

Tags: c++, stl

If i have a stl map from string to int and i want to print all the int values sorted - how can i do that?

Comment: @Danh Current consensus is to close by "quality": <http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha> Since "quality" is not measurable, I just go by upvotes. ;-) Likely it comes down to which question hit the best newb Google keywords on the title.

Comment: @CiroSantilli烏坎事件2016六四事件法轮功 Good to know

Comment: @Danh: In the general case that is true -- for a `map<key_type, value_type>`, it's not necessarily true that comparisons even exist for `value_type`.  For the specific case of `map<string, int>`, comparison by value is possible.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You cannot sort a map by its values due to the implementation of the map.

If you want to emit the elements in the map in such a sorted order then you have to first dump the map contents into a vector (say) and sort that vector:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct less_second {
    typedef pair<T1, T2> type;
    bool operator ()(type const& a, type const& b) const {
        return a.second < b.second;
    }
};

map<string, int> mymap;
// …

vector<pair<string, int> > mapcopy(mymap.begin(), mymap.end());
sort(mapcopy.begin(), mapcopy.end(), less_second<string, int>());
```

Or alternatively, just copy the values from the map, leaving the keys, and sort the resulting vector directly.

Comment: When you put both `first` _and_ `second` into the vector anyway, why not put it into a `std::map<int,std::string>`?

Comment: @sbi: well obviously because that would be *waaay* too simple and obvious. :-P

Comment: @sbi, values may be repeated.

Comment: @sbi: also, you would duplicate data having `std::map<int,std::string>` and `std::map<std::string,int>`.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, @sbi: imho, the most compact (as for amount of both code and data) solution would be the `boost::multi_index_container`.

Comment: @Nick and @malleor: You're right, of course, `std::multimap<int,std::string>` would be better.

Comment: Note that if you have a typedef for your map (`typedef map<string, int> map_t`), you may be tempted to write `vector<map_t::value_type> mapcopy`. But this doesn't work because there the first (key) type is const really (`pair<const string, int>`).

Answer (score 6):

You can copy all the values into vector and sort it.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

int get_second( pair<string, int> i ){ return i.second; }

int main(int argc, char* argv){
  map<string, int> m;
  m["tt"] = 2;
  m["rr"] = 1;
  m["ee"] = 3;

  vector<int> v( m.size() );
  transform( m.begin(), m.end(), v.begin(), get_second );
  sort( v.begin(), v.end() );
  for (int i=0; i<v.size(); i++) cout << v[i] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this automatically. [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) uses first value (nomen omen 'key') to sort content.

Instead, you can use [`boost::multi_index_container`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/multi_index/doc/examples.html#example4).

Answer (score 3):

If you need to do this multiple times, it might be more efficient to keep two separate containers, e.g. your map and a sorted container like [`set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/set/) or [`multiset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multiset/) for storing the sorted ints, rather than having to create a container and sort it on the fly. But then you have to keep them synchronized, which could get mucky. You could encapsulate that by wrapping them in a class, or better yet use a [`boost::multi_index_container`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot sort a map, it's an *associative* container, not a sequential, and associated containers are sorted by some internal order.

If you want to only print the `int` values, you could put them into a `std::vector`, sort the vector, and print the values.

Comment: I think he wants to print all strings sorted by their ints :)

Comment: `std::map`s are not sorted by 'some' order.. They're sorted by explicitly given key values, in this case strings.

Comment: @malleor: Yes, I know. And a `std::unordered_map` is sorted by some other order. I wrote about _associated containers_, not about `std::map` in that phrase.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `vector`, I'd rather just copy them to a `set<int>`:

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

set<int> map2set(map<string, int> const& m) {
 set<int> r;
 for (map<string, int>::const_iterator b = m.begin(), e = m.end(); b != e; ++b)
   r.insert(b->second);
 return r;
}

int main() {
 map<string, int> m;
 m.insert(make_pair("hello", 42));
 m.insert(make_pair("world", 24));
 set<int> s = map2set(m);
 copy(s.begin(), s.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "\n"));
}
```